# How to delete an item in a tuple of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I understand that tuple is immutable. Therefore, I am trying to convert the tuple to a list first then delete the item.

My original tuple is `('monkey', 'camel', ('python', 'elephant', 'penguin'))`. It's a tuple including another tuple inside. I want to delete `'python'`.

Firstly I defined a flatten() function (I found it from the forum):

```
def flatten(foo):
    for x in foo:
        if hasattr(x,'__iter__') and not isinstance(x,str):
            for y in flatten(x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x
```

Then define the delete function:

```
def tuple_without(original_tuple,item_remove):
    lst=flatten(list(original_tuple))  #  convert the original tuple to list and flatten it
    return list(x for x in lst if x !=item_remove)

print(tuple_without(new_zoo,'python'))
```

It works and the results shows as:

```
['monkey', 'camel', 'elephant', 'penguin']
```

I would like to know if there is any better and more Pythonic solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a recursive function as below

```
def removeItem(myTuple, item):
     myList = list(myTuple)
     for index, value in enumerate(myList):
         if isinstance(value, tuple):
             myList[index] = removeItem(value, item)
         if value==item:
             del myList[index]
     return myList
```

This just loops through the tuple, converting it to a list, re-calling itself on finding another nested tuple and deleting the found item. This also keeps the nested structure, no flattening required!

Also, I just noticed that your code above does not actually use the new list from `list(original_tuple)` list. Instead, it is just flattened and then a new tuple is made using a tuple comprehension with the contents of the flattened tuple (which is now a generator). So at no point in your example is the contents of a list ever edited (just to clarify things a bit).

So in the line `lst=flatten(list(original_tuple))`, you do not need the list function.

Answer (score 1):

This code can do the job for you:

```
def exclude_words(the_tuple, exclude=[]):

    new_list = []

    for value in the_tuple:
        if type(value) == tuple:
            new_list.extend(exclude_words(value, exclude))
        elif not value in exclude:
            new_list.append(value)

    return new_list
```

Comment: Old school, but that makes it easily understandable :-). I just prefer "value not in" to "not value in"...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to turn the tuple into a list before you flatten it. As this flatten() version is really a generator of all the values, you can just use its result in the generator expression:

```
def tuple_without(original_tuple,item_remove):
    return list(x for x in flatten(original_tuple) if x !=item_remove)
```

You could remove the `list()` call here as well; if you need a list then you can turn it into one where you call this function, and if you only need to loop over it there you can just use the returned generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

For loop the tuple and check if an item is a tuple. Append the item to the list if its not a tuple. If the item is a tuple then for loop that tuple for the item you want and append to list what you want from that tuple.

```
a = (1,2,(3,4))
b = [ ]

for x in a:
    if type(x) is tuple:
        for y in x:
            if y != 3:
                b.append(y)
    else:
        b.append(x)


print(b)
>>[1,2,4]
```